# Can a check for null be removed here?

Tags: javascript

It would be to provide stronger checking for iterable objects, and reduce the control structure.

I've taken the code below and modified it to get rid of the initial check for null.  By explicitly checking for something with keys we can provide a seemingly stronger guarantee that something will not slip by ( obj == null ),  and we can eliminate 1 of the 4 control statements.  The update is in snippet 2.

Also, by adding in a check for `&& obj` we can avoid errors being thrown, which is what it seems the original check was for.

`obj == null` will detect `undefined` and `null`.

From [Underscore](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L77):

**Snippet1**

```
var each = _.each = _.forEach = function(obj, iterator, context) {
    if (obj == null) return;
    if (nativeForEach && obj.forEach === nativeForEach) {
      obj.forEach(iterator, context);
    } else if (obj.length === +obj.length) {
      for (var i = 0, l = obj.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (iterator.call(context, obj[i], i, obj) === breaker) return;
      }
    } else {
      for (var key in obj) {
        if (_.has(obj, key)) {
          if (iterator.call(context, obj[key], key, obj) === breaker) return;
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

The new snippet.  The line directly after the comment has been modified.

**Snippet 2a**

```
var each = _.each = _.forEach = function(obj, iterator, context) {

    // modify - obj &&

    if (nativeForEach && obj && obj.forEach === nativeForEach) {
      obj.forEach(iterator, context);

    // modify - obj &&

    } else if (obj && (obj.length === +obj.length)) {
      for (var i = 0, l = obj.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (iterator.call(context, obj[i], i, obj) === breaker) return;
      }
    } else {
      for (var key in obj) {
        if (_.has(obj, key)) {
          if (iterator.call(context, obj[key], key, obj) === breaker) return;
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

If 0 of the 3 cases are matched, it will fall through and `return undefined` by default, i.e, implicitly.

Will this removal work correctly?

Per discussion:

**Snippet 2b**

```
var each = _.each = _.forEach = function(obj, iterator, context) {
    if (obj && (obj.length === +obj.length)) {
      for (var i = 0, l = obj.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (iterator.call(context, obj[i], i, obj) === breaker) return;
      }
    } else {
      for (var key in obj) {
        if (_.has(obj, key)) {
          if (iterator.call(context, obj[key], key, obj) === breaker) return;
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: What is the problem with first snippet?  Using guard conditions is good practice.

Comment: What do you mean by "*By explicitly checking for something with keys*"?

Answer (score 0):

> we can eliminate 1 of the 4 control statements

…but you will have to add those `obj &&` checks in the others, and you even have to introduce another if-condition around the object loop. You're making the code more complicated and slower with that "improvement".

> Will this removal work correctly?

Well, you've changed the control flow. There's no behavioral change if you pass in arrays or other objects, but your new snippet will not enumerate booleans and numbers (like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Uxnqq/3/)) and not try to iterate empty strings. Not sure what you consider to be "correct".

Comment: it's not possible to enumerate a number or a boolean using a `for-in` ...http://jsfiddle.net/Uxnqq/2 ...

Comment: @pure_code.mom: It's not possible to assign properties to primitive values, that's right. But you can still use them in for-in-enumerations, where they are implicitly casted to objects: http://jsfiddle.net/Uxnqq/3/ - please change your downvote to an upvote :-) I'm not saying that this is relevant of course, I just wanted to show that there is a tiny difference.

Comment: I didn't change anything, just added the demo link. And the first part of the answer (about "*making the code more complicated and slower*") is still valid. If you clarify your question about "correctness" (change it to *Does it work the same on arrays and objects?* or something) I'm happy to adapt my answer.

Comment: I took out the additional if...in case someone passes the thing a Number w/ prototyped properties on it ( is this reality ? ), etc. So now if you can edit.  I'm talking about replacing the single if statement with two `obj &&` now.  And take note that `for in` has no problem ignoring `null` and `undefined`.

Comment: Also, take note, that nativForEach is slower than all other methods of looping through an array, I've seen two jsperfs on this now...so that would be the next step, to simply remove that if statement all together.  The end function would be faster and simpler as it reduces to an if and an else statement.

Comment: ... the current version is simpler, in that the reduction is from 4 to 3 statements, if you want it to be faster take off the native call.  If you have hope that it will be implemented correctly one day, and don't want to fiddle with it, leave it in.

Comment: I've explained how to reduce snippet 1 to snippet 2b to make it faster and simpler.

Comment: OK, your snippet 2b makes sense and is fine. Taking one `if` out in favor of two `&&`s (in 2a) did not. Btw, if you're looking for a performance-optimized Underscore replacement check out http://lodash.com/

Comment: opinion vs fact .... unless you do the jsperf, you don't know that adding in two `obj &&` in place of one `if` is faster or slower...also, which one is more readable is a matter of opinion ... so 2a is fine as well ...

Comment: `You're making the code more complicated and slower with that "improvement".` ... this is wrong and sarcastic, change this, and I'll change my vote.

Comment: My comment on the complicacy and slowness of 2a compared with 1 was neither wrong nor sarcastic. [Here's a performance test](http://jsperf.com/extra-if).